# Find missing date in a php array

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

I have a php array as follows :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeAttendance] => Array
                (
                    [attendance_id] => 1
                    [arrival_datetime] => 2016-11-01 03:31:00
                    [status] => Present
                )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeAttendance] => Array
                (
                    [attendance_id] => 2
                    [arrival_datetime] => 2016-11-03 06:31:00
                    [status] => Present
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeAttendance] => Array
                (
                    [attendance_id] => 3
                    [arrival_datetime] => 2016-11-06 07:31:00 
                    [status] => Present  
                )
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeAttendance] => Array
                (
                    [attendance_id] => 4
                    [arrival_datetime] => 2016-11-08 19:31:00
                    [status] => Present
                )
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeAttendance] => Array
                (
                    [attendance_id] =>5
                    [arrival_datetime] => 2016-11-10 08:00:00
                    [status] => Present
                )
        )
)
```

Here in this array we can see the attendance details from date '2016-11-01' to '2016-11-10' and some dates are missing here like  '2016-11-02','2016-11-04','2016-11-05','2016-11-07' and '2016-11-09' . 
Now I want to check the missing dates from the date between '2016-11-01' to '2016-11-10' and insert those missing dates into the array with status = "absent". Give some suggestion please.

Comment: Is this array limited to only one month or any month can be there?

Comment: @d.coder just only for a particular month

Comment: Can we change the structure of above array? And what is the use of this array then fro you?

Answer (score 1):

First collect all dates, sort, generate daterange between firts, and last then is missing insert

```
$data = [

    [
        'EmployeeAttendance' => [
            'attendance_id'=>1
            ,'arrival_datetime'=>'2016-11-01 03:31:00'
            ,'status'=>'Present'
        ]
    ]
,[
        'EmployeeAttendance' => [
            'attendance_id'=>1
            ,'arrival_datetime'=>'2016-11-05 03:31:00'
            ,'status'=>'Present'
        ]
    ]
    ,[
 'EmployeeAttendance' => [
        'attendance_id'=>1
        ,'arrival_datetime'=>'2016-11-11 03:31:00'
        ,'status'=>'Present'
    ]
]
];

$dates = [];
foreach ($data as $x => $d) {
    $dates[] = substr($d['EmployeeAttendance']['arrival_datetime'],0,10);
}
sort($dates);
$period = new DatePeriod(
    new DateTime($dates[0]),
    new DateInterval('P1D'),
    new DateTime(end($dates))
);
foreach ($period as $d) {
    $key = $d->format('Y-m-d');
    if (!in_array($key,$dates)) {
        $data[] = [
            'EmployeeAttendance' => [
                 'arrival_datetime'=>$key
                ,'status'=>'absent'
            ]
        ];
    }
}
print_r($data);
```

Comment: Is it possible to insert the missing dates in a ascending order

Comment: simply sort after fill `uasort($data,function ($a,$b) {
   return $a['EmployeeAttendance']['arrival_datetime'] > $b['EmployeeAttendance']['arrival_datetime'];
});`,

Comment: i have done it like this way :  foreach ($dataas $key => $d) {
          $sort[$key] = strtotime($d['EmployeeAttendance']['arrival_datetime']);
     }
     array_multisort($sort, SORT_ASC, $data);

Comment: @AjayKrishnaDutta You could consider accepting the answer

Comment: @AjayKrishnaDutta I'm sorry troubling you, but none of your questions including this one has accepted answer, [upvoting is not enough there is a tick bellow vote button](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this:

```
    $a = array(array('EmployeeAttendance'=>array('attendance_id'=>1,'arrival_datetime'=>'2016-11-01 03:31:00','status'=>'Present')),array('EmployeeAttendance'=>array('attendance_id'=>2,'arrival_datetime'=>'2016-11-03 04:31:00','status'=>'Present')),array('EmployeeAttendance'=>array('attendance_id'=>3,'arrival_datetime'=>'2016-11-07 07:31:00','status'=>'Present')),array('EmployeeAttendance'=>array('attendance_id'=>4,'arrival_datetime'=>'2016-11-09 05:31:00','status'=>'Present')));
    foreach($a as $key=>$data){
        $presentDates[] =  date("j", strtotime($data['EmployeeAttendance']['arrival_datetime']));// will give array of present dates array(1,3,7,9);
    }
    $first = reset($presentDates);
    $last = end($presentDates);
    $total = range($first,$last); // will give all dates between start and end
    $absentArr = array_diff($total, $presentDates); // will give missing dates array(2,4,5,6,8)
    foreach($absentArr as $value){
    $a[]['EmployeeAttendance'] = array('arrival_datetime'=>'2016-11-'.$value,'status'=>'Absent');
    }
  print_r($a);
```